# Time and space complexity of python function which calculates sum of principal diagonal elements

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o, space-complexity

```
def diagonalSum(matrix, n):
    sum=0
    i=0
    for row in matrix:
        sum+=row[i]
        i+=1
    return sum
```

How to calculate the space and time complexity of the above code. It calculates the sum of principal diagonal elements in a matrix.

Comment: What is `n`? This parameter is unused in your function.

Answer (score 0):

- considering metrics is a square metric, [if not your code will output the wrong answer.]
  the time complexity of the algorithm in `O(sqrt(n))`. here `n` is the total number of elements in the metric.
- It's hard to give a straight answer for space complexity other than an empirical answer.
  since there forms a single 2D array with `n` number of elements, space complexity proportionate to `n`.

**NOTE**:

> in the worst case[time complexity] calculation case like this for simple iterative process, we count the number of iterations in each loop, and if there are nested loops multiply the number else sum up and use `macro convention to give the final result.
> [for further reading](http://sd.blackball.lv/library/Introduction_to_Algorithms_Third_Edition_(2009).pdf)